# How is the function $x^+$ defined?

Tags: limits, functions

Can I define the function $x^+$ in the following way (here $\epsilon \ge 0)$

$$ x^+ = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} (x + \epsilon)$$ where $\epsilon \ne 0$.

Same question for $x^- = \lim_{\epsilon\to0} x - \epsilon$.

I thought that these functions (if they are correct) can be used to define a bijective mapping from $[0,1] \to (0,1)$ in the following way
$$ f(x) = x^+ \mid 0 \le x \lt \frac{1}{2} $$
$$f(x) = x^- \mid \frac{1}{2} \lt x \le 1$$
$$ f(x) = 1/2 \mid x = \frac{1}{2} $$.

Comment: If you want to define $x^+=x$, you can.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Not exactly, see I wanted a bijection from $[0,1] \to (0,1)$. So I was trying to generate a function $x^+$ which maps a number $x$ to a number slightly greater than $x$.

Comment: According to these definitions, $x^+=x^-=x$.

Comment: Then no, there is no continuous bijection between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: To find a bijection, you are going to need discontinuities.

Comment: @RebeccaBlack "*which maps a number $x$ to a number slightly greater than $x$*" You seem to be referring to [infinitesimals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal) which are sometimes studied as a part of [non-standard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis).  In standard analysis however, the only infinitesimal is zero.  There is no such thing as "the smallest positive real number" and as a result we get what Shalop and other users already mentioned; your "function" is merely the identity function and maps numbers to themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of the functions is fine.  They are a complicated way of defining the identity function, because for all $x$ we have $x^+=x^-=x$.  The problem in your application is that $0^+=0$ and $1^-=1$, so you have not defined a mapping from $[0,1] \to (0,1)$.  The image of $[0,1]$ is again $[0,1]$.